# Get client’s real ip through Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy

The platform is a Docker host, using the `jwilder/nginx-proxy` image as the front-facing reverse proxy. It auto-generates the nginx config, and restarts the container, as other containers with specific metadata are created & deleted.

A Webserver container is then deployed for a specific domain name, e.g. `www.domain.com`. I need to see the actual client’s IP in the webserver’s log file. Currently I am getting the nginx-proxy container’s IP.

Following the usage guide, site-specific config can be deployed in the `/etc/nginx/vhost.d/` directory. I have created mine with the same `www.domain.com` filename and it contains:

```
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

set_real_ip_from 172.19.0.0/16;
```

I create a new dummy container to force the nginx-proxy to create a new config and reload. Logging onto the console of the nginx-proxy container, the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default` file’s `443 server{}` block contains an `include` statement with the above filename. So it should be loading the config. I see no change in the client IPs in the Webserver log file. This include is not included in the `80 server{}` block - is this correct?

I have also tried editing the `nginx.tmpl` file that performs the auto-generated nginx-proxy config. In the container, it resides at `/app/`. Another post suggested replacing the “`log_format`” command to use `$http_x_forwarded_for` instead of `$remote_addr`. This had no effect.

Due to the auto-gen nature of nginx-proxy, I’m not entirely sure how to manually edit the running config, nor how to debug what values are currently set or which logic of the config scripts is being applied.